# Allocating and initializing object in one function, sending it to other and releasing it there works?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

```
// ViewController.m - implements downloader's protocol downloadComplete
- (void) startDownload
{
        Downloader *downloader = [[downloader alloc] init];
        [downloader setDelegate:self];
        [downloader startDownloading];
        // [downloader release] or autorelase makes the program crash
}

- (void) downloadComplete: (id) downloadedContent
{
        [downloadedContent release]; // will this release the object allocated in the first function? Or do I set [self release] in dealloc of Downloader.m? Or any other way to do it?
}    

// Downloader.m

- (void) startDownloading
{
      // download some data
      [[self delegate] downloadComplete:self];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I see, `- (void) downloadComplete: (id) downloadedContent` is a delegate method. It's a good habit to release only the objects you own (except where explicitly said) and the delegate do no own that object. It's far better and clearer to release the object in `dealloc` method of `ViewController.m`

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's not very cocoa-ish. I'd suggest creating `downloader` as an instance method, allocating it when needed and releasing it in dealloc. If you can use download functionality several times in same controller instance - make sure to release and nil-out downloader object before creating it.